# Google DFP - How to make Ad Units truly responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-dfp

I have followed the various guides on how to display different ads for different resolutions. This works fine to an extent.

If you visit the site below and have the resolution between 768 and 900, you should notice some horizontal scrolling on the leaderboard advert. How would I get this to resize accordingly until the breakpoint (768px wide) when the other advert comes into play?

On that second advert, I'd like to apply a similar principle.

**Test Site:** https://www.iq-mag.net/dfp.php

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>GPT Training - Responsive Test Page</title>
<script async src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];

  var gptAdSlots = [];
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {

  var leaderboard1 = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([0, 0], [456, 349]).addSize([768, 200], [900, 200]).build();
  var mpu1 =           googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([0, 0], [241, 198]).addSize([768, 200], [376, 310]).build();

  gptAdSlots[0] = googletag.defineSlot('/210178423/Desktop_Leaderboard', [456,349], 'MobileLeaderboard').defineSizeMapping(leaderboard1).addService(googletag.pubads());
  gptAdSlots[1] = googletag.defineSlot('/210178423/MPU', [241,198], 'MobileMPU').defineSizeMapping(mpu1).addService(googletag.pubads());
  googletag.enableServices();
 });
</script>
<style>
#MobileLeaderboard,#MobileMPU {border:10px green dashed;}
#MobileLeaderboard {width:900px}
#MobileMPU{width:376px}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 768px){
  #MobileLeaderboard {width:456px}
  #MobileMPU {width:241px}
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Leaderboard</h1>
<div id="MobileLeaderboard">
<script>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {
   googletag.display('MobileLeaderboard');
 });
</script>
</div>
<h1>MPU</h1>
<div id="MobileMPU">
<script>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {
   googletag.display('MobileMPU');
 });
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not recommended to amend the size of an ad for 2 reasons. First to guarantee the readability of the advertiser message. Second, because DFP adcalls are generated within iframes and it might become difficult to amend the size of the banner. I recommand you to add more breakpoints in your sizeMapping. For instance, you could display a 728x90 ad unit...